# Sentence correction for a given sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, grammaticality

There are (1)/only five breads(2)/ left in the(3)/ kitchen for your
breakfast(4)/No error(5).

What is the correct form for the sentence. The sequence is correct but there is a problem with certain word.

Comment: It may be different in your culture, but in most English-speaking countries _bread_ is the name of the substance. Individual portions would be _pieces/slices_ of bread (cut from a loaf) or _rolls_ (there are other local names for individual servings baked separately). We wouldn't say _five breads_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These would all be correct:

- There are only five slices of bread left in the kitchen for your breakfast.
- There are only five loaves of bread left in the kitchen for your breakfast.
- There are only five rolls left in the kitchen for your breakfast.
- There are only five buns left in the kitchen for your breakfast.

"Bread" is not a noun that can be pluralized meaningfully on its own, as there is no explicit unit of one "bread" to pluralize. It needs to be denominated in slices, loaves, etc.

Other nouns with a similar limitation are: "air", "money", "gasoline", ...